# Mongo documents with documents with documents (a tree!)

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm begining to use MongoDB, and I have a collection that has documents that may have subdocuments, that may have subdocuments... a tree.

```
{
a:[
    {
    a:[
        {
        },
        {
        },
    ]
    },
    {
    }
 ],
 ...
},
{
a:[
    {
    a:[
        {
        },
        {
        },
    ]
    },
    {
    }
 ],
 ...
}
```

Should I do it like that explicitly, should I store each subdocument in another collection and store IDs on an array, or should I use a traditional relational SQL DB for this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a document-oriented database. Data that is usually broken up into multiple tables (i.e. "normalized") in a relational database is often stored together in document databases, sometimes in a single collection.

MongoDB is "schema-less," meaning it has no fixed schema, so the structure of its documents is very flexible. You can have sub-documents or even arrays in your documents, as you showed in your tree structure. This makes designing a NoSQL schema very challenging, since you have many options to choose from. Really, the best schema depends on your application and the **queries you will perform against the database**. In SQL databases, the data is normalized based on the data itself, without regard to queries.

Keep in mind that MongoDB doesn't support joins, so anything you "split up" into multiple collections will need to be joined manually. Go ahead and take advantage of MongoDB's flexible schema and try different options. Documents with many levels of nesting will make queries more complicated, so there's a trade-off as usual.

Comment: I have written a bit more about the problems of embedding in http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/